# MySQL: Select User Only If They Completed All Items?

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables: users and missionInfo. I need to select classes only when all of the users who are in that class completed all missions.

```
users table:
userID  classID
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2

missionInfo table:
userID  missionID   
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
3       3
4       1
5       1
5       2
```

So, I should get back classID 1 because users 1 thru 3 all completed all missions 1 thru 3 and are all part of the same class.

Help?

Comment: Sounds simple. But how exactly do you determine if a mission has been completed?

Comment: If it is in the table, then it is completed.

Comment: How do you know how many total missions there are?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the total number of missions (3) being hard-coded, or is there some way to query the number of missions that need to be completed?

Comment: Can a user complete a mission more than once?

Comment: Hard coding mission numbers if fine. The actual number is 15, but I can edit that.

Comment: If a user redoes a mission, that row is updated, rather than a new one added. So, no, the max number rows a user can have in missionInfo is 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT classID FROM (
  SELECT   classID
  FROM     users JOIN missionInfo USING (userID)
  GROUP BY classID, missionID
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT userID) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u WHERE u.classID = users.classID
  )
) AS t
GROUP BY classID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @total_number_of_missions
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ef93/8).

The `DISTINCT` can be omitted if `(userID,missionID)` will only appear once in the `missionInfo` table.

The inner query returns `classID` for every mission that has been completed by all that class's users; the outer one restricts the results to only those classes who have completed the specified number of missions.

Comment: Boom! Nailed it! Thank you so much!